# Laravel Many to Many, attach one model, multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

I have a many to many relationship between 2 models: Tours and Locations, and I have some extra pivot-table fields (days and nights of staying in each location).
Everything is set up and working just fine.

Each Tour can have multiple locations, the point is, every tour can have the same location, MULTIPLE times:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| tour_id | location_id | days | nights | ordering |
----------------------------------------------------  
|    1    |      1      |   4  |    3   |     1    |
----------------------------------------------------  
|    1    |      2      |   5  |    5   |     2    |
----------------------------------------------------  
|    1    |      1      |   2  |    1   |     3    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

So we have:

```
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $tour->locations()->attach($location->id, [
         'days' => $location->days,
         'nights' => $location->nights,
         'ordering' => $location->ordering
    ]);
}
```

This will result in adding only 2 rows to pivot table.
How can we attach a single Location to a tour, MULTIPLE times?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you are attaching the modal, thus it only adds one relationship. You will have to manually add again, if want an extra relationship.

The loop added all 3 at once. Now you want to add a 4th location ?

```
$location4 = Location::find(4);

$tour->locations()->attach($location4, [
    'days' => $location4->days,
    'nights' => $location4->nights,
    'ordering' => $location4->ordering
]);
```

To avoid overriding, use `syncWithoutDetaching()`

```
$tour->locations()->syncWithoutDetaching($location4, [
    'days' => $location4->days,
    'nights' => $location4->nights,
    'ordering' => $location4->ordering
]);
```

Comment: $locations contains all 3 sets of data:  `[{"id": "1", "days": "4", "nights": "3", "ordering": "1"},{"id": "2", "days": "5", "nights": "5", "ordering": "2"},{"id": "1", "days": "2", "nights": "1", "ordering": "3"}]` so we end up `attach` ing all 3. but it somehow overrides first location with the third one.

Comment: locations are dynamic and coming from a request. there is no way I separate them like this. maybe use `syncWithoutDetaching` in the original loop?

Comment: Yes, try that in the original loop